# Positioning a play button and a video background section in bootstrap

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have the following bootstrap code:

```
<section>
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row">
      <video>
        ...source...
      </video>
      <button>Play</button>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
```

The section has a height set to 560px. The video tag has a height: auto and a width: 100%. How can I add a Play Pause button that stays consistently in the same spot of the viewable video area no matter the screen size?

Comment: Use absolute positioning in % units.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Use relative units of measurements like `%` and `em`
- Use a font icon inserted as a pseudoclass with `::before` or `::after`
- Add `position:relative` to `.row` and `position:absolute` to `#play` in order to accurately position `#play`.
- Add `bottom` or `top` of `#play` at this value: `calc(50% - height of #play/2)`. Note: some font icons are not perfectly centered vertically so use that formula and adjust accordingly.
- Add `left` or `right` of `#play` at this value: `calc(50% - width of #play/2)`.
- Add `z-index:-1` to `.row` and `z-index:1` to `#play`

### Demo

```css
.row {
  display: table-cell;
  position: relative;
  z-index: -1
}

#play {
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 1;
  /* 50% - (height/2) [Using a font icon, adjust accordingliy] */
  bottom: calc(50% - 5em);
  /* 50% -(width/2) */
  left: calc(50% - 4em)
}

#play.idle::before {
  content: '\2bc8';
  width: 8em;
  /* AR 16:9 is width * .5625 */
  height: 4.5em;
  color: cyan;
  font-size: 8em
}
```

```html
<section height='560'>
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row">
      <video id='vid' src='http://media6000.dropshots.com/photos/1381926/20170326/005611.mp4' width='100%' height='auto'></video>
      <div id='play' class='idle'></div>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
```

Comment: Thanks. I knew to use absolute positioning and the bottom property but didn't think about calc!

Answer (score 0):

You can set the position of your button at "absolute", then position it with Top, bottom, left, right.

Btw the absolute position gonna be set relatively to the nearest positioned ancestor of your Play/Pause button so if your viewable video area  is set to relative it's always gonna be in the same spot relatively to your video area.